# SQL rule to only display records with age between 26 and 38

Tags: sql

I am trying to query data so only the records of people aged between 26 and 38 are shown. There is no age column and instead, I use the data of the birth column. The current SQL code for WHERE:

```
WHERE Student.DoB = (Year(Now())-Year([DoB]))>26  
      Student.DoB = (Year(Now())-Year([DoB]))<38;
```

The query is inaccurate and it is not just displaying the records of people aged between 26 and 38.

I need help in identifying what may be causing this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL). Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your query just calculates the age, so just use it. Do not compare it with DoB.

So it should be like this:

```
  WHERE (Year(Now())-Year(Student.DoB)) > 26 
  AND
  (Year(Now())-Year(Student.DoB)) < 38
```

or if your Database engine supports `BETWEEN` keyword

```
  WHERE (Year(Now())-Year(Student.DoB)) BETWEEN 26 AND 38
```

Answer (score 0):

Use And between the conditions

```
WHERE (Year(Now())-Year(Student.[DoB]))>26 
      AND
      (Year(Now())-Year(Student.[DoB]))<38;
```

Or

```
WHERE (Year(Now())-Year(Student.DoB)) BETWEEN 26 AND 38
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, after modifying the code, no records at all show. Is there any more info I can give to help solve the issue?